# How to fix Index error(list) if he only appears at while loops

Tags: python

My Problem is that I've got a list of numbers and if try to save every element of the list in a variable to split them and so on I get the error list index out of of range. But if I try it whithoul and wihle loup and do it manually for 2 or 3 elements of the list it works.

I've tried a lot of differrent possibilitys which I found here on stackoverflow and on reddit, but northing worked.

```py
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

f = 2, 'f'
u = 3, 'u'
th = 5, 'th'
o = 7, 'o'
r = 11, 'r'
c = 13, 'c/k'
g = 17, 'g'
w = 19, 'w'
h = 23, 'h'
n = 29, '29'
i = 31, 'i'
j = 37, 'j'
s = 53, 's/z'
t = 59, 't'
b = 61, 'b'
e = 67, 'e'
m = 71, 'm'
l = 73, 'l'
ng = 79, 'ng/ing'
oe = 83, 'oe'
d = 89, 'd'
a = 97, 'a'
ae = 101, 'ae'
y = 103, 'y'
eo = 41, 'eo'
p = 43, 'p'
x = 47, 'x'
ia = 107, 'ia,io'
ea = 109, 'ea'


runen = [f, u, th, o, r, c, g, w, h, n, i, j, s, t, b, e, m, l, ng, oe, d, a, ae, y, eo, p, x, ia, ea]

runen1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 43, 47, 107, 109]
kek = list(combinations(runen1, 2))
zero = 0
null = 0
while(zero < len(kek)):
    jayjay = kek[null]
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(',', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace("'", '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace('(', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(')', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(' ', '')
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(jayjay)
    del kek[null]
    null = null +1

print(newlist)
```

I expceted as an output the new list
but the output is error: list index out of range

Comment: Could you write what output you expect for some smaller list? For example `[2, 6, 3]`?

Comment: Put the full stack trace and _all_ the code in the question. When I run your code, first thing I get is `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`, as I assume you are using `itertools.combinations`. Please provide `combinations` if that's not the one you're using

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The code seems very obscure. What is `newlist` supposed to contain? My guess is something like `[str(a) + str(b) for a,b in combinations(runen1,2)]`

Comment: Of course :)The List which gets done by itertools cmbinations would then look like [('2', '3'), ('3', '6'), ('2', '6'). The new list would look like [23, 36, 26]

Comment: I'll now post the hole code

Comment: My intention is the subset-sum thing. So with the new list I could take the element rom the list and just take the the 2 numbers as subsetts. Afterwoods I woold change the numbers into letters to get words. This is for encycription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this required a few mods to reproduce your error:

```
from itertools import combinations #### Added ####
runen1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 43, 47, 107, 109]
kek = list(combinations(runen1, 2))
zero = 0
null = 0
while(zero < len(kek)):
    jayjay = str(kek[null]) #### Added ####
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(',', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace("'", '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace('(', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(')', '')
    jayjay1 = jayjay.replace(' ', '')
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(jayjay)
    del kek[null]
    null = null +1

print(newlist)
```

After these mods, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stacktest.py", line 7, in <module>
    jayjay = str(kek[null]) #### Added ####
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why are you going out of bounds? Well, you're accessing `kek[null]`, but the condition that your `while` loop is checking is `zero < len(kek)`. Those are not the same.

Secondly, you almost *never* need to use indexes in Python. It's not like C, where indexing is the only way to accomplish iteration. If you want to iterate, you can do:

```
for item in kek:
    print(item)
    # or do more complex things with item
```

Third, you don't want to reinitialize `newlist = []` during the loop. Put it outside the loop.

Fourth, don't call `del` on something you're iterating over.

Fifth, no need for `jayjay1`, just modify `jayjay` in place.

Putting it all together:

```
from itertools import combinations
runen1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 43, 47, 107, 109]
kek = list(combinations(runen1, 2))
newlist = []
for jayjay_tuple in kek:
    jayjay = str(jayjay_tuple)
    jayjay = jayjay.replace(',', '')
    jayjay = jayjay.replace("'", '')
    jayjay = jayjay.replace('(', '')
    jayjay = jayjay.replace(')', '')
    jayjay = jayjay.replace(' ', '')
    newlist.append(jayjay)

print(newlist)
```

This is close to your (original) code, and will also work if you bump up the number of combinations.

Learning to debug is an invaluable skill to have if you're serious about programming. I highly recommend you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and learn to use `pdb` (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`). Errors will keep coming up, and you don't want to have to post to SO every time they do.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this unnecessarily complicated. Just use a list comprehension:

```
import itertools
runen1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 43, 47, 107, 109]
newlist = [int(str(a) + str(b)) for a,b in itertools.combinations(runen1,2)]
```

If you want to generalize from 2. You could use:

```
def kspots(nums,k):
    return [int(''.join(str(a) for a in c)) for c in itertools.combinations(nums,k)]
```

Then, for example, `kspots(runen1,17)` will be the (large) list that you seem to want. That list has 21,474,180 elements and takes over a minute to generate on my machine, so you might want to use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension (replace the outer `[,]` by `(,)`)

Comment: And how can I use this method, if I want to do it for 17 spots for example @John Coleman

Comment: The code doesn'nt work at 17 spots. If I take your code and just change the runen(1, 17), than I get the output: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)